# as softly and aesthetically as it deserves

Tags: word-usage, comparison

I would like to know if the following comparison, parallelism is grammatically correct :

"as softly and aesthetically as it deserves"

**or rather** "as soft and aesthetical as it deserves"

I am talking about a song whose beats are very slow and soft...

Thank you !

Comment: Please, give a whole sentence, it will help you receive an acurate answer.

Comment: Much depends on whether the context requires an ***adverb*** or an ***adjective***. But in the former case, both ***soft*** and ***aesthetic*** ([*please* not ***aesthetical**!*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=aesthetic%2Caesthetical%2Caesthetically&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Caesthetic%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Caesthetical%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Caesthetically%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Caesthetic%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Caesthetical%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Caesthetically%3B%2Cc0)) could be used as "flat adverbs". But without a ***specific*** context, it's Off Topic

Answer (score 1):

> Play this song **as softly and aesthetically as** it deserves.

> This song is **as soft and aesthetic as** that one we heard the other day.

It mostly depends on whether the context requires an adverb or an adjective.